# Cannot play animation in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, animation, android-animation

Hi guys i am a beginner in android development, i try to make an animation for my activity but it's not working, i have change the alpha in my layout xml but still it's not working.

Maybe you can help me out to find the solution for this problem

here is my code:

// WelcomeActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.dicodingsocialmedia.databinding.ActivityWelcomeBinding
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.data.model.ErrorResponse
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.data.repo.AuthRepo
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.data.service.ApiClient
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.ui.auth.RegisterActivity
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.ui.story.StoryActivity
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.utils.AuthPreferences
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.utils.CustomEditText
import com.example.sosmeddicoding.utils.dataStore
import com.google.gson.Gson
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import retrofit2.HttpException

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityWelcomeBinding
    private lateinit var authButton: Button
    private lateinit var editText: CustomEditText

    private lateinit var viewModel: WelcomeViewModel
    private lateinit var authPreferences: AuthPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityWelcomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        authButton = binding.buttonLogin
        editText = binding.password

        setMyButtonEnable()



        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if (s.toString().length < 8) {
                    editText.error = "Password tidak boleh kurang dari 8 karakter"
                } else {
                    editText.error = null
                }
                setMyButtonEnable()
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            }
        })


        binding.registerHere.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, RegisterActivity::class.java))
        }

//        // Check Token
        authPreferences = AuthPreferences.getInstance(application.dataStore)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            authPreferences.getAuthToken.collect { savedToken ->
                if (savedToken != "") {
                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, StoryActivity::class.java))
                } else {
                    this@WelcomeActivity
                }
            }
        }

        authButton.setOnClickListener {
            showLoading(true)
            val email = binding.email.text.toString()
            val password = binding.password.text.toString()

            val authService = ApiClient.getApiService(authPreferences.USER_TOKEN ?: "")
            val authRepo = AuthRepo(authService, authPreferences)
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
                this,
                WelcomeViewModelFactory(authRepo)
            ).get(WelcomeViewModel::class.java)

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                try {
                    val successLogin = viewModel.loginVM(email, password)
                    if (successLogin.error == false && successLogin.loginResult != null) {
                        val token = successLogin.loginResult.token
                        if (token != null) {
                            authPreferences.saveToken(token)
                        }
                        showLoading(false)
                        showToast(successLogin.message.toString())
                        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, StoryActivity::class.java))

                    }
                } catch (e: HttpException) {
                    showLoading(false)
                    val jsonInString = e.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
                    val errorBody = Gson().fromJson(jsonInString, ErrorResponse::class.java)
                    val errorMessage = errorBody.message
                    if (errorMessage != null) {
                        showToast(errorMessage)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@WelcomeActivity,
                            "Register Failed, please register again",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }




    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun showLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
        if (isLoading) {
            binding.cardView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            binding.cardView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


    private fun setMyButtonEnable() {
        val result = editText.text
        authButton.isEnabled = result != null && result.toString().isNotEmpty()
    }


}
```

and here is my layout xml
// activity_welcome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sosmeddicoding.ui.WelcomeActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/travel10">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_login"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingVertical="16dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        style="@style/CornerRounded"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <com.example.sosmeddicoding.utils.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/action_login"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLoading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLoading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Loading"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/auth_question"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/register_here"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_here"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/register_here"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <!--    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="323dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="41dp"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.086" />-->

    <!--    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="323dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="501dp"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tabLayout"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tabLayout"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />-->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```